# How to create a Callback from C#/.NET via COM to C++?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-c++, com

I'm currently using a C#/.NET library using the COM interface from C++. Just as a simple fictive example to illustrate what I'm currently doing:

I have a C#/.NET component declaring and exporting COM interfaces.

```
[Guid("example-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000")]
public class MyObj : IMyObj
{
    void DoSomething(string someArgument);
}
```

Now I export a type library which is imported in my C++ application:

```
#import "MyObj.tlb" named_guids auto_rename

void someFunc()
{
    MyObjPtr myObj;
    myObj.CreateInstance(CLSID_MyObj);
    myObj->DoSomething(_bstr_t(L"foo"));
    // ...
}
```

In reality the C#/.NET component complex with many interfaces and methods. It is used from C++ in a multithreaded way.

Everything works really fine, but I would like to enable logging for the C#/.NET library. The internals of the C#/.NET library should be able to send the log messages back to the C++ application in order to use the already existing logging environment there to write log messages.

```
    [C++ Logging System] <--- [C#/.NET Component]
```

**What is the best way to create a kind of callback for this situation?**

The callback should only take a simple string. E.g.:

```
public interface ILogger {
    void Write(string message);
}
```

How to realize this on the C++ side?

(Meanwhile answered here: [How to implement COM callback interface in C++, from C# assembly, using `#import` and `tlb` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808299/how-to-implement-com-callback-interface-in-c-from-c-sharp-assembly-using-i))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that COM provides a pattern for event handling, although to be fair I never could get my head around it. A quick search brought me on [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9014/Understanding-COM-Event-Handling) page, which looks like a good explanation.

Personally, I wouldn't make things more complicated than necessary; I think if you let your .NET code implement a `RegisterLogger(ILogger instance)` / `UnregisterLogger(ILogger instance)`, and mark the `ILogger` interface as a dual interface (i.e. it inherits from IDispatch), then your .NET code can use it to log messages through - but make sure you use the late-bound way of invoking it - e.g. see [here](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/C-Sharp/Using-Late-Bound-COM-Objects/3/)

On the C++ side, define an `ILogger` interface that inherits from `IDispatch`, so it can
be used with late binding, and have your C++ code invoke the .NET `RegisterLogger()`
method, passing in your own implementation of `ILogger`.
Because of the use of late binding, the C++ `ILogger` interface need not be known on
the .NET Side, it just needs matching method signatures.

Comment: So, I can derive in C++ from the `ILogger` interface and pass an object pointer to the COM interface? How is the ownership situation? Is this C++ object owned by the C++ application, or does the COM/C#/.NET part handle this object?

Comment: 1) No, there are 2 ILogger interfaces, one in .NET and one in C++. As long as they both derive from IDispatch, share the same method signatures and are invoked through late binding, each side can work with its own version of the ILogger interface while still being compatible. 2) Ownership is handled just as with all COM objects, the instantiating side (your C++ code) remains owner, whereas the client (your .NET code) uses IUnknown's AddRef and Release to indicate if the owner can clean up the instance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you don't *need* IDispatch interfaces (i.e. late binding), but then it becomes essential that the memory layout of the interface is the same on both sides - i.e. you'll need the .NET code declare the interface and have the C++ side import it.
Come to think of it, you're probably already doing this everywhere else in your code, this idea isn't too bad ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the Answer and sorry for my delay. I will try your solution as soon as possible.

Comment: It actually works, but it didn't answer my second question. It's not that simple to implement a such COM interface without using ATL or MFC. But luckily the C# component is only interested in the IUnknown interface and not in the IDispatch one. Therefore the implementation of a such class is simple.

Comment: I answered my second question in this question: [How to implement COM callback interface in C++, from C# assembly, using `#import` and `tlb` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808299/how-to-implement-com-callback-interface-in-c-from-c-sharp-assembly-using-i)

Comment: Good to hear that it's working! I also left a reply on your other question.