# How to implement COM callback interface in C++, from C# assembly, using `#import` and `tlb` file?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++, com, callback

The following fictive and minimal example explains the question.

You have a C#/.NET library which exports the interface via COM to use from C++.

```
   [C++ Application] --- is using ---> [via COM] [C#/.NET Library]
```

The library on the C#/.NET side looks like this:

```
[Guid("example-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000")]
public class MyObj : IMyObj
{
    void SetLogger(ILogger logger);
    void DoSomething(string someArgument);
}
```

The assembly is compiled and a `tlb` file is exported called `MyObj.tlb`. This `tlb` file is imported in the Application using the `#import` statement from Visual-C++:

```
#import "MyObj.tlb" named_guids auto_rename

void someFunc()
{
    MyObjPtr myObj;
    myObj.CreateInstance(CLSID_MyObj);
    // How to set the logger?
    myObj->DoSomething(_bstr_t(L"foo"));
    // ...
}
```

Everything works really fine, but you would like to enable logging for the C#/.NET library. The internals of the C#/.NET library should be able to send the log messages back to the C++ application in order to use the already existing logging environment there to write log messages.

```
    [C++ Logging System] <--- log message --- [C#/.NET Component]
```

You already declared the interface for the logger in the C#/.NET component.

```
[Guid("example-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000")]
public interface ILogger
{
    void WriteLine(string line); 
}
```

The question is:

**What is the simplest way to implement a `Logger` class, using the `ILogger` interface, for the C++ application?**

(Without using ATL or MFC)

Answer (score 4):

The `ILogger` interface derives from `IDispatch`, but the C# interop layer does not actually use the `IDispatch` interface. Therfore only the `IUnknown` interface needs to be implemented.

See the section "Limiting the interface in C# to early binding using `IUnknown`" below, how you can change your C# component to avoid the `IDispatch` interface completely.

The implementation for the `ILogger` interface described in the question will look like this:

```cpp
#import "MyObj.tlb" named_guids auto_rename

class Logger : public ILogger
{
public:
    Logger(MyLogger log)
        : _log(log), _refCount(1)
    {
    }

    virtual ~Logger()
    {
    }

public: // Implement ILogger
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall raw_WriteLine(BSTR message) {
        // Convert BSTR and write to _log.
        return S_OK;
    }

public: // Implement IDispatch
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfoCount(UINT *pctinfo)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfo(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo **ppTInfo)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR *rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID *rgDispId)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS *pDispParams, VARIANT *pVarResult, EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, UINT *puArgErr)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

public: // Implement IUnknown
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppvObject)
    {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown) {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IUnknown*>(this); 
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        if (riid == IID_IDispatch) {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<IDispatch*>(this); 
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        if (riid == IID_ILogger) {
            *ppvObject = static_cast<ILogger*>(this) ;
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }
        *ppvObject = nullptr;
        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef()
    {
        return InterlockedIncrement(&_refCount);
    }

    virtual ULONG __stdcall Release()
    {
        return InterlockedDecrement(&_refCount);
    }

private:
    MyLogger _log;
    long _refCount;
}
```

Please note the following important things about this implementation:

- The reference count is just implemented to look like a COM reference count. Because this object will be owned by the C++ application, there is no need to implement the destruction of the object.
- All `IDispatch` methods just return an error code. They are never called by C# interop. See the section "Working implementation of `IDispatch`" for details how to implement these methods.
- IN a real project, the imported types form the `tlb` are all placed in a own namespace.
- The `class` declaration and implementation should be separated in a header and implementation file.

The code is used like this in the C++ application:

```
bool MyApp::start()
{
    try {
        HRESULT hresult;
        MyObjPtr myObj;
        hresult = myObj.CreateInstance(CLSID_MyObj);
        if (hresult != S_OK) { 
            return false;
        }
        // Create the logger object which acts as callback for the C# library
        _logger = new Logger(_myLogger);
        // Assign this logger
        myObj->SetLogger(_logger);
    } catch (const _com_error &comError) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Limiting the interface in C# to early binding using `IUnknown`

User [Astrotrain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843345/astrotrain) pointed out a simplification to remove `IDispatch`: If your component ist just used by this C++ Application and therefore does not require late binding using the `IDispatch` interface, you can add the `InterfaceType` attribute to the interface to remove one binding.

This would look like this in our example:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
 Guid("example-0000-0000-0000-0000000000000")]
public interface ILogger
{
    void WriteLine(string line); 
}
```

The `ILogger` interface is now directly derived from `IUnknown`. Now you can omit all empty implementations of the `IDispatch` interface.

The downside is your component can only be used from languages which are supporting early binding. If this C++ Application is the only user of your component, this is no problem.

### Working implementation of `IDispatch`

User [Paulo Madeira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800524/paulo-madeira) provided a complete example how to implement all `IDispatch` methods using `ITypeInfo`. The following example shows the `Logger` class, omitting all methods which are shown in the example at the begin of this answer. Make sure you read the notes below.

```
class Logger : public ILogger
{
    // ctor, dtor, ILogger and IUnknown implementation

public: // Implement IDispatch
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfoCount(UINT *pctinfo)
    {
        if (pctinfo == nullptr) {
            return E_POINTER;
        }
        *pctinfo = (getTypeInfo() != nullptr) ? 1 : 0;
        return S_OK;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetTypeInfo(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo **ppTInfo)
    {
        if (ppTInfo == nullptr) {
            return E_POINTER;
        }
        *ppTInfo = nullptr;
        if (iTInfo != 0) {
            return DISP_E_BADINDEX;
        }
        ITypeInfoPtr typeInfo(getTypeInfo());
        if (typeInfo == nullptr) {
            return E_NOTIMPL;
        }
        *ppTInfo = typeInfo.Detach();
        return S_OK;
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR *rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID *rgDispId)
    {
        if (rgDispId == nullptr) {
            return E_POINTER;
        }
        *rgDispId = 0;
        if (!IsEqualIID(riid, IID_NULL)) {
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        }
        ITypeInfoPtr typeInfo(getTypeInfo());
        if (typeInfo == nullptr) {
            return E_NOTIMPL;
        }
        if (cNames == 0) {
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        }
        return typeInfo->GetIDsOfNames(rgszNames, cNames, rgDispId);
    }

    virtual HRESULT __stdcall Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS *pDispParams, VARIANT *pVarResult, EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, UINT *puArgErr)
    {
        if (pDispParams == nullptr) {
            return E_POINTER;
        }
        // IDispatch and ITypeInfo allows this to be NULL
        if (pVarResult != nullptr) {
            VariantInit(pVarResult);
        }
        // IDispatch and ITypeInfo allows this to be NULL
        if (pExcepInfo != nullptr) {
            ZeroMemory(pExcepInfo, sizeof(EXCEPINFO));
        }
        // IDispatch allows this to be NULL, ITypeInfo does not
        UINT argErr;
        if (puArgErr == nullptr) {
            puArgErr = &argErr;
        }
        *puArgErr = 0;
        if (!IsEqualIID(riid, IID_NULL)) {
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        }
        ITypeInfoPtr pTypeInfo(getTypeInfo());
        if (pTypeInfo == nullptr) {
            return E_NOTIMPL;
        }
        return pTypeInfo->Invoke(
            static_cast<ILogger*>(this),
            dispIdMember,
            wFlags,
            pDispParams,
            pVarResult,
            pExcepInfo,
            puArgErr);
    }

private:
    static ITypeInfo* getTypeInfo()
    {
        if (!_hasTypeLib) {
            ITypeLibPtr typeLib;
            if (SUCCEEDED(LoadRegTypeLib(LIBID_MyObj, 1, 0, 0, &typeLib))) {
                ITypeInfoPtr typeInfo;
                if (SUCCEEDED(typeLib->GetTypeInfoOfGuid(IID_IDispatch, &typeInfo))) {
                    if (!InterlockedCompareExchange(&_hasTypeLib, 1, 0)) {
                        _typeInfo.Attach(typeInfo.Detach());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _typeInfo.GetInterfacePtr();
    }

private:
    static LONG volatile _hasTypeLib;
    static ITypeInfoPtr _typeInfo;
    // other variables
};

// Static definitions in cpp file:
LONG volatile Logger::_hasTypeLib;
ITypeInfoPtr Logger::_typeInfo;
```

Note the following things about this example above:

- You have to replace the `LIBID_MyObj` with the library identifier of your library. It has a similar naming.
- The full implementation is only required if your COM component requires late binding.
- The `class` declaration and implementation should be separated in a header and implementation file.
- The `static_cast<ILogger*>(this)` casts are required to make sure the pointer, which is passed as `void*` pointer, points to the right *vtable*.

Comment: You can implement the `IDispatch` members with the `ITypeInfo` you can get from loading the type library, e.g. [LoadRegTypeLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221121(v=vs.85).aspx)(LIBID_MyObj, REGKIND_NONE, &pTypeLib); pTypeLib->[GetTypeInfoOfGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221185(v=vs.85).aspx)(IID_ILogger, &pTypeInfo); -- then make `GetTypeInfoCount` return 1, `GetTypeInfo` return `pTypeInfo` for `iTInfo == 0`, and `GetIDsOfNames` and `Invoke` delegate to `pTypeInfo`.

Comment: If you're not supporting the late binding functionality from C++, it's better to not have your ILogger interface derive from IDispatch. From what I can gather, it looks like using `InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)` on your C# ILogger interface will do that for you.

Comment: @Astrotrain You are absolutely right. But I keep the dual interface to be able to use the same C# components form other applications. I will add your information to my answer.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Can you provide a complete example? In this case I would extend my answer with an additional section to show how to implement all `IDispatch` methods.

Comment: @Flovdis, please review my edit and see how it works out for you.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Perfect, thank you! I will review and test your implementation, but add it as additional section at the end of the answer.

Comment: I can't see my edit right now, but I think I missed a few things: the use of `LIB_MyObj` and passing a neutral LCID (`LOCALE_NEUTRAL`) to `LoadRegTypeLib`.

Comment: @PauloMadeira I added your example as a new section to the answer. I found a small problem in your `GetTypeInfo()` implementation. You wrote `*ppTInfo = _pTypeInfo.Detach();` which should be `*ppTInfo = pTypeInfo.Detach();`. If you copy'n'pasted this from a own project, make sure you fix the source. The `#import` also creates a named GUID for the library, using the `named_guids` option. This leads to a simpler implementation of your `EnsureTypeInfo()` method. Again, thank you for the example!

Comment: Thanks, your edits made it better (coding style, NULL -> nullptr).  BTW, I haven't tried it, but if you really wanted to, you could have it work for different LCIDs if `getTypeInfo` would take one as an argument and cache type infos by LCID.  This would support different names (or name comparison on lookup) for different locales, much like Office does.  I'm just posting this comment about LCIDs for posterity, you don't have to edit the answer.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to `static_cast` `this` to `ILogger` when invoking `ITypeInfo::Invoke`.  We must provide the expected vtable.  In your `QueryInterface`, you should make this cast too, in case you ever implement another interface.

Comment: @PauloMadeira Good point! I changed the examples to make sure there are no vtable problems.